# Naive vector swapping only partially working

Tags: c++, sorting

I have a paired vector `<string,int>pairedv` containing data measurement names and indices.  The size, at least of the test data, is around 780 measurements, approximately half water, half other liquid.  Because I want the file output from this program to be as user-friendly as possible, I'm trying to presort the output into two sections, a water section and "other" section.

In the final loop of the code below, I have a `bool vector` mask for when its corresponding measurement name doesn't contain "water" or any common variant.  If `bool[i]` returns true, it increments a counter to be used later, else it finds the next "water" measurement, and switches the values for the two elements.

---

```
#include <algorithm>
#include <iostream>
#include <iterator>
#include <string>
#include <vector>

using namespace std;

bool IsWater(const string &str1){
    if(str1.find("water")!=string::npos)
        return (true);
    //test file water measurements contain "*water*" only, remainder are for redundancy
    if(str1.find("Water")!=string::npos)
        return (true);
    if(str1.find("WATER")!=string::npos)
        return (true);
    if(str1.find("H2O")!=string::npos)
        return (true);
    if(str1.find("h2o")!=string::npos)
        return (true);
    return false;
}



int main(int argc, char* argv[]){
    //pairedv is initialized with <string,int> values
    //corresponding to measurement name, index

    vector<bool> boolv;
    for(int i=0;i<pairedv.size();i++){
        //fill bool vector with true if name contains water or variant
        if(IsWater(pairedv[i].first))
            boolv.push_back(true);
        else
            boolv.push_back(false);
    }

    //initialize 'x' as counter; will be used later to split std::sort into halves
    int x=0;
    for(int i=0;i<boolv.size();i++){
        if(boolv[i])
            x++;            //if water, only increment x
        else{               //if NOT water, swap with next "water" found

            for(int i2=i+1;i2<boolv.size();i2++){
                if(boolv[i2]){

                    string tempstr=pairedv[i].first;
                    int tempint=pairedv[i].second;
                    pairedv[i]=pairedv[i2];
                    pairedv[i2]=make_pair(tempstr,tempint);
                }
            }
        }
    }

    //...
return 0;
}
```

---

If I run this last loop twice, it does sort the water measurements before the "not water" measurements.  However, this is definitely a sub-optimal solution; what can I do to sort in one pass?

Comment: Use the standard library sort.  You just have to implement a comparison function.

Comment: [std::sort](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/sort)

Comment: @AnonMail Trying that didn't work for me.  It gave me an even more garbled output.

Comment: @poison_us don't reinvent the wheel.  You can post your code and the specific error.

Comment: @AnonMail My code *is* posted.  It doesn't output an error, so how could I post an error?  It simply does not organize the input in a uniform fashion.

I even said that there is a workaround, but that entails doing the same exact thing twice, and that's far from optimal.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You might use `std::partition` (or `std::stable_partition`):

```
std::vector<std::pair<std::string, int>> pairedv /* = ...*/;

auto isPairWater = [](const auto& p) { return IsWater(p.first); };
auto it = std::partition(pairedv.begin(), pairedv.end(), isPairWater);

// water would be [pairedv.begin(); it[
// not water would be [it, pairedv.end()[
```

Comment: The code you typed returns error:  

`error: binding 'const std::__cxx11::basic_string<char>' to reference of type 'std::__cxx11::string& {aka std::__cxx11::basic_string<char>&}' discards qualifiers|`  

Removing the `const` does fix this, and it does work, accepted.  But why do I have do omit `const`?  Is it because of the Lambda expression?  (self-taught, as of yet Lambda is foreign to me)

EDIT: Disregard the comments on `const`, I see your edit to my code now.  Is it necessary to `const` a variable that isn't changed by the function anyway?

Comment: Adding `const` allows to better explain intend, and compiler enforce this check.